# Calculate computer usage on a particular day [SQL]

Tags: sql, window-functions

We need to find out how many hours for day = 1/2/2020 was the machine running.

State
1 = Started Computer
0 = Stopped Computer

| id | State | EventTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 1 | 1/3/2017 14:00 |
| a | 1 | 1/2/2020 14:00 |
| a | 0 | 1/2/2020 18:00 |
| a | 1 | 1/2/2020 23:00 |
| a | 0 | 1/3/2020 14:00 |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using (it can't be Postgres, as that doesn't have a `datediff()` function)

Comment: `nvl` would suggest Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this

```
select id,hoursrunning from 
(
select id, state, 
datediff(
     hours,
       LEAD(EventTimestamp,1,'1/2/2020 24:00') OVER (partition by id  order by EventTimestamp ),
       EventTimestamp ) as hoursrunning
from Instance_Dim
where date(EventTimestamp) = '1/2/2020')T
where state=1
```

Comment: Thanks, This works for id 'a' but not for id 'b' where the computer is running since 2017